# Date Time to String Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need to convert a Snowflake TIMESTAMP_TZ(9) to String format,but throwing this error

> "Date '27/02/2020' is not recognized"

Tried all of these:

```
TO_CHAR( date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as date,   
TO_VARCHAR(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as date, 
TO_CHAR( date, 'DD.MM.YYYY') as date,
```

Comment: Please dont spam tags!

Comment: I'm lost.  Are you starting with a date or a string?

Comment: Are you sure that the column "date" is a timestamp? That error looks like what you would get if it was a string data type.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the problem if I write a query like this:

```sql
select to_char(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
from (
    select '27/02/2020'::date date
)

-- Date '27/02/2020' is not recognized
```

And I can fix that query with this:

```sql
select to_char(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
from (
    select to_date('27/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date
)
```

So if that's your problem, first you need to parse the dates with `to_date()` in that particular format.

Comment: tying this approach, but got this error: SQL compilation error: error line 160 at position 4 too many arguments for function [TO_DATE(DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')] expected 1, got 2

Comment: What's the `select typeof(date)`? Also sharing the schema of the table would help. I see the question says its of `TIMESTAMP_TZ(9)` - but something seems wrong if that's the case -- we need to debug further. Can you share the results of `select date` too?

Comment: What you're reproducing there is a failure to cast a *string* value to a *date* data type. According to the question the source column is *timestamp_tz*, although that doesn't make sense based on the code and reported error.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths - I know, but I'm doing my best with what the question provided. Hopefully Steven can add more context, or the mystery might remain unsolved.